Retrieve the Answer from the Local Chatbot in language which the User has asked in
I have created a local chatbot in python 3.10.10. I have used Langchain_community, and langchain_core, Chroma, Streamlit to build the chatbot application.
However, when I ask the question in German language, it gives me an answer in English language. I expect the answer in the same language which User has asked in the query (Question Tab).
I have tried using the package from langdetect import detect, but it still does not give me an answer in User langauge.
could anyone help me achieving this thing?

Not sure which LLM you are using from your question. But I would suggest add a line in system prompt saying "Always answer in the language of the user question" - something like that. And give it a try.
Alternatively, you need to use StructuredOutputParser() to translate to another language using external service after you get the LLM response.
More here: https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/3306

okay, thank you for the answe. Do you think that the Embedding Model does also influence in terms of getting an answer in multiple language(s)?

I have been using the mistral:latest as my LLM so far. What do you think about it? Should I change the model?

Don't change the model. See if you could give the instruction i said above as system prompt. and let me know what happens

It works but I would say 70%. Because somethings I have got the answer in English despite of writing the question in German.

I wonder could you answer my another question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78982378/hugging-face-llm-for-chatbot-with-rag-chain

Responded to the q.
